# Drools functions

Tags: java, function, drools

Recently I'm working with drools and I want to make some special checks on some objects. I need to use functions in the `when` section of the rule, but I'm getting an error. Example:

```
function boolean newFunction(int a){
  if(a>0)
    return true;
  else
    return false;
}

rule "new rule"
salience 100
dialect "mvel"
when
  eval(newFunction(1))
then
  System.out.println("OK");
end
```

The error i get always is:

```
unable to resolve method using strict-mode: java.lang.Object.newFunction(java.lang.Integer)
```

Is there no support on drools for functions in `when`section?

Thanks!

Comment: As mentioned in the answers, Drools functions are not for use in the LHS. However, I'm assuming that you are asking this because you're actually looking to achieve re-use of code in your LHS. To achieve this, you can use the "extends" keyword. i.e. `rule "a rule" extends "another rule"`. Unfortunately, this rather useful piece of functionality is not mentioned in the Drools documentation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The short answer is: no.

This is because the facts need to be in the working memory.

What you can do, is to have a rule that takes all types of a certain class from the working memory, applies a function in the *then* section and inserts that new value in the working memory.

## edit

This answer, originally posted on 2012, is not more relevant as newer versions of drools do support functions on the `when` clause.

Answer (score 3):

Very likely an MVEL or an integration bug - function call adapters did not box/unbox primitive types. 
I see the question is quite old, but the problem has been since fixed (tested with 6.3.0-SNAPSHOT). For older versions, I'd try using boxed types : function boolean newFunction( Integer a ) ...

Answer (score 2):

Along the lines of the selected answer above, after some experimentation I found that it is possible to create an external java method, whose class can be imported into the rules file, and wrapped in a MVEL function wrapper (Boolean) which can then can be called from the LHS as a parameter to an eval statement.

```
[External Java POJO_Class.myMethod]


import com.mypackage.POJO_Class;


function Boolean myFunctionName() {
   POJO_Class myClass = new POJO_Class();
   return myClass.myMethod(Parameters);
}



rule "Test Rule"
    when
      eval ( myFunctionName(parameters) )
    then
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain why you are getting the error you are getting, but I was using the following for some debugging yesterday in a query (an LHS so I'm guessing same as a rule)

```
function boolean say(Object s) { 
      Debug.log("Say %s\n", s); 
      return true; 
}
```

the query just did `eval(say($object))` to help me see whether it ever got invoked. I'm running a snapshot of 6.1 from a week or so ago. Maybe try getting it working (doing anything) just taking Object and work from there - it might be Number or Integer is where you end up on the argument rather than int?